# Tiny legend text, and histogram with tmap

Tags: r, tmap

I am using tmap to make a series of maps. I have most of the code working right, the numbers on the righthand side explaining the legend colors, and the histogram are all very tiny:

[image]

Dummy code:

```
library('dplyr')
library('sf')
library('tigris')
library('shiny')
library('leaflet')
library('RColorBrewer')
library('tmap')
library('mapview')
library('rosm')
library('tmaptools')


#create dummy data
az_2000 <- tracts(state = "Arizona", year = 2000) %>% 
  select(c(CTIDFP00)) %>% rename("geoid" = "CTIDFP00")
az_2000 <- st_transform(az_2000, 4326)

az_2000$value <- sample(0:5, nrow(az_2000), TRUE)


#setup basemap
basemap <- osm.raster(
  st_bbox(az_2000), 
  zoom = 6,
  type = "cartolight",
  crop = TRUE
)


#map
my_tmap <- tm_shape(basemap) + 
  tm_rgb() +
  tm_shape(az_2000) + 
  tm_polygons(col = "value",
              palette = "-viridis",
              title = "2020 US Census",
              legend.hist = TRUE,
              lwd = 0.05) + 
  tm_layout(title = "Count of Things",
            frame = FALSE,
            legend.outside = TRUE)

my_tmap
```

I have tried including the code legend.text.size, and legend.hist.size and setting that to larger numbers, but I just keep getting errors

```
#map
my_tmap <- tm_shape(basemap) + 
  tm_rgb() +
  tm_shape(az_2000) + 
  tm_polygons(col = "value",
              palette = "-viridis",
              title = "2020 US Census",
              legend.hist = TRUE,
              lwd = 0.05) + 
  tm_layout(title = "Count of Things",
            frame = FALSE,
            legend.outside = TRUE,
            legend.text.size = 3,
            legend.hist.size = 3)

my_tmap
```

Error:
Legend labels were too wide. The labels have been resized to -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1. Increase legend.width (argument of tm_layout) to make the legend wider and therefore the labels larger.
Error in grid.Call(C_convert, x, as.integer(whatfrom), as.integer(whatto),  :
Viewport has zero dimension(s)

How do I fix this?

UPDATE:

I tried @mgrund's solution below. I like how their map looks, but I'm still getting different results:

[image]

I can get better results by playing around with the legend.hist.width and legend.hist.height per their recommendations. But I can't get the font size to come out the same between the histogram and the legend, and when I do it I have gray outlines between the tracts. Any advice on how to get this more consistent?

Comment: Let us know the actual errors, please. A viewport error let's you know that your view/plot pane in R Studio is not sized well for viewing the plot. Other errors may be noting that the legend.text.size argument is relative to other arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting smaller values for the sizes parameters does not generate the mentioned errors, while it's still readable. Furthermore, I would suggest to play around with the `legend.hist.width` and `legend.hist.height` parameters.

```
#map
my_tmap <- tm_shape(basemap) + 
  tm_rgb() +
  tm_shape(az_2000) + 
  tm_polygons(col = "value",
              palette = "-viridis",
              title = "2020 US Census",
              legend.hist = TRUE,
              lwd = 0.05) +
  tm_layout(title = "Count of Things",
             frame = FALSE,
             legend.outside = TRUE,
             legend.text.size = 1,
             legend.hist.size = 1,
             legend.hist.width = 0.75)

my_tmap
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but still get a pretty different looking map - see my update.  Would greatly appreciate more help!